# How can I prevent two bookings from being made at the same time in my SQLite database in Python?

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter

Firstly, I apologise for my unhelpful question from the other day. It wasn't my intent to seem lazy or disobey site rules, I was just a bit stuck.

Secondly, I did later manage to produce that system and get it working without needing any help, but I have encountered a smaller, more specific problem within the code for the system that I was wondering whether anyone could help me with.

The issue I'm having is that while the system is letting me book timeslots perfectly, it is letting more than one user book an identical timeslot at a time that is already taken. So for instance, if I were wanting to book an in-person timeslot at 10am on 12/27/21, but someone else had already taken that slot, the system would book me in at that time too regardless of whether someone else had already booked it, which shouldn't be allowed.

In terms of what I've tried; I first tried making my SQL command for checking the database records be to check for booking IDs for the corresponding date, time, and whether the booking was online or in-person.

However, after some testing, I realised that this probably wouldn't flag up any similarity between the input and an existing record, as the booking ID would be different for the other user. So I then changed it to check for timeslot dates booked for the user's desired time and whether it was online or in-person, and if one of the dates in the database matched the user's desired date, the user should have been prevented from booking that time.

This didn't work, however; two users are still allowed to book timeslots at the same time, and I'm struggling to figure out why. I checked that the cursor is bringing back results from the database, and it is finding the identical date like I would have expected, so I don't think that's the issue here.

For reference, my code is as follows:

```
    InPerson=tk.Tk()
    InPerson.title("Book In-Person Timeslots")

    InPersonGreetingMessage=Label(InPerson, text="Here are the available in-person timeslots. In-person timeslots can be used to shop online if you wish.")
    InPersonGreetingMessage.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2)

    InPersonCalendar=Calendar(InPerson, selectmode = "day", year = 2021, month = 12, day = 2)
    InPersonCalendar.grid(row=1, column=0)

    #Subroutine for selecting a date from the GUI calendar
    def SelectDate():
        #Subroutine for searching timeslots
        def SearchForTimeslots():
            def InPersonTimeslotAt10am():                
                sqliteConnection = sqlite3.connect('GUISHOP.db')
                cursor = sqliteConnection.cursor()
                DataRetrievalStatement=f'SELECT Date FROM Bookings WHERE Time = "10am" AND OnlineOrInPerson = "In-Person"'
                cursor.execute(DataRetrievalStatement)
                print(cursor.fetchone())
                if Date == cursor.fetchone():
                    TenAMUnavailable=tk.Tk()
                    TenAMUnavailable.title("Time Unavailable")
                    
                    SorryUnavailable=Label(TenAMUnavailable, text="Sorry, no in-person timeslots at 10am are available on this date. Please check a different time: ")
                    SorryUnavailable.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2)

                    BackButton=tk.Button(TenAMUnavailable, text="Pick A Different Time", command=SearchForTimeslots)
                    BackButton.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2)

                    TenAMUnavailable.mainloop()
                else:
                    BookingID=random.randrange(10**5, (10**6)-1)
                    BookingID_str=str(BookingID)
                    NHSNumber_str=NHSNumber.get()
                    OnlineOrInPerson="In-Person"
                    Time="10am"

                    InsertBookingIntoSQLite = "INSERT INTO Bookings (BookingID_str, NHSNumber_str, Date, Time, OnlineOrInPerson)VALUES(?,?,?,?,?);"

                    BookingDataTuple=[BookingID_str, NHSNumber_str, Date, Time, OnlineOrInPerson]

                    cursor.execute(InsertBookingIntoSQLite, BookingDataTuple)
                    sqliteConnection.commit()

                    TenAMConfirmed=tk.Tk()
                    TenAMConfirmed.title("Timeslot Booking Confirmed")

                    Confirmation=Label(TenAMConfirmed, text="Thank you for booking an in-person timeslot at 10am on" + Date)
                    Confirmation.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2)
                    
                    BookingDetails=Label(TenAMConfirmed, text="You have been sent a file containing a unique QR code that will grant you access to shop during your timeslot. Your 6-digit booking ID is:" + BookingID_str)
                    BookingDetails.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2)
                    
                    SearchForTimeslots=tk.Tk()
            SearchForTimeslots.title("Available In-Person Timeslots on Date Chosen")

            AvailableTimeslots=Label(SearchForTimeslots, text="Here are the available in-person timeslots on the date you've chosen: ")
            AvailableTimeslots.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2)

            TenAM=tk.Button(SearchForTimeslots, text="10am", command=InPersonTimeslotAt10am)
            TenAM.grid(row=1, column=0)

            TenThirtyAM=tk.Button(SearchForTimeslots, text="10:30am", command=InPersonTimeslotAt1030am)
            TenThirtyAM.grid(row=2, column=0)

            ElevenAM=tk.Button(SearchForTimeslots, text="11am", command=InPersonTimeslotAt11am)
            ElevenAM.grid(row=3, column=0)

            ElevenThirtyAM=tk.Button(SearchForTimeslots, text="11:30am", command=InPersonTimeslotAt1130am)
            ElevenThirtyAM.grid(row=1, column=1)

            TwelvePM=tk.Button(SearchForTimeslots, text="12pm", command=InPersonTimeslotAt12pm)
            TwelvePM.grid(row=2, column=1)

            TwelveThirtyPM=tk.Button(SearchForTimeslots, text="12:30pm", command=InPersonTimeslotAt1230pm)
            TwelveThirtyPM.grid(row=3, column=1)

            OnePM=tk.Button(SearchForTimeslots, text="1pm", command=InPersonTimeslotAt1pm)
            OnePM.grid(row=1, column=2)

            OneThirtyPM=tk.Button(SearchForTimeslots, text="1:30pm", command=InPersonTimeslotAt130pm)
            OneThirtyPM.grid(row=2, column=2)

            TwoPM=tk.Button(SearchForTimeslots, text="2pm", command=InPersonTimeslotAt2pm)
            TwoPM.grid(row=3, column=2)

            TwoThirtyPM=tk.Button(SearchForTimeslots, text="2:30pm", command=InPersonTimeslotAt230pm)
            TwoThirtyPM.grid(row=1, column=3)

            ThreePM=tk.Button(SearchForTimeslots, text="3pm", command=InPersonTimeslotAt3pm)
            ThreePM.grid(row=2, column=3)

            ThreeThirtyPM=tk.Button(SearchForTimeslots, text="3:30pm", command=InPersonTimeslotAt330pm)
            ThreeThirtyPM.grid(row=3, column=3)

            FourPM=tk.Button(SearchForTimeslots, text="4pm", command=InPersonTimeslotAt4pm)
            FourPM.grid(row=1, column=4)

            FourThirtyPM=tk.Button(SearchForTimeslots, text="4:30pm", command=InPersonTimeslotAt430pm)
            FourThirtyPM.grid(row=2, column=4)

            FivePM=tk.Button(SearchForTimeslots, text="5pm", command=InPersonTimeslotAt5pm)
            FivePM.grid(row=3, column=4)

            SearchForTimeslots.mainloop()
            
        Date=InPersonCalendar.get_date()
        date.config(text="The date you have selected is: " + Date)

        def SubmitNHSNumberForTimeslot():
            NHSNumber_str=NHSNumber.get()
            if not NHSNumber.get():
                Denied=Label(InPerson, text="Please input your NHS Number.")
                Denied.grid(row=6, column=0, columnspan=2)
            else:
                Accepted=Label(InPerson, text="Your NHS Number has been accepted. Search for timeslots now: ")
                Accepted.grid(row=6, column=0, columnspan=2)
                
                SearchForTimeslotsButton=tk.Button(InPerson, text="Search for Timeslots", command=SearchForTimeslots)
                SearchForTimeslotsButton.grid(row=7, column=0, columnspan=2)

        NHSNumberLabel=Label(InPerson, text="Please input your NHS Number for confirmation before proceeding: ")
        NHSNumberLabel.grid(row=4, column=0)
        
        NHSNumber=Entry(InPerson, width=30)
        NHSNumber.grid(row=4, column=1)

        NHSNumberSubmission=tk.Button(InPerson, text="Submit NHS Number", command=SubmitNHSNumberForTimeslot)
        NHSNumberSubmission.grid(row=5, column=0, columnspan=2)   

    PickDate=tk.Button(InPerson, text="Select Date", command=SelectDate)
    PickDate.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=20)

    date = Label(InPerson, text="")
    date.grid(row=3, column=0)

    InPerson.mainloop()
```

(The bit I'm mainly focusing on here is the InPersonTimeslotAt10am subroutine and the SQLite database within, but I just included the whole InPerson subroutine for context and to show where I'm getting everything from.)

Does anyone know what my problem might be? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have called `cursor.fetchone()` twice.  If there is only one record returned, the second call will get nothing.  Also `cursor.fetchone()` return a tuple if there is record found, so comparing `Date` with a tuple may return `False`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! If you're referring to where I put "print(cursor.fetchone())", that was just for my own use more than anything else.

Comment: Or have I put it somewhere else that I haven't noticed?

Comment: Update: I have solved the problem myself! I removed the "print(cursor.fetchone())", as I literally put that there for my own use, and I also changed the SQL command back to looking for a booking ID aligning with the date, time and mode picked, as well as making the booking only occur if cursor.fetchone() == None. If any other outcome comes, the user is blocked from booking.

Comment: That seems to be working well from what I can ascertain; thank you for your help! As it turns out, removing the second cursor.fetchone() that I didn't actually need made it work!